# How to custom style a specific ionic component

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3

i new to ionic ,
i

```
 have this lines of code : 

  <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button :default-href="pageDefaultBackLink"></ion-back-button>
          <ion-button router-link="/memories/add" color="light">---1---</ion-button>
          <ion-button router-link="/memories/add" color="light">---2---</ion-button>
          <ion-button router-link="/memories/add" color="light">---3---</ion-button>
          <ion-button router-link="/memories/add" color="light">---4---</ion-button>
   </ion-buttons>
```

what i'm trying to do is add some custom style to the last ion-button component , but i have no idea how i can do that ,
Nb: i'm using vue 3 with ionic 6

Comment: Do you know css ? yes : just add a class or inline style.

Comment: i tried , it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS, either globally or on the corresponding Sass file (.scss) and add that to a class or ID which you then target in the CSS file.

Some styles you can change directly using raw CSS, some you have to access the Shadow DOM.

For example, your `ion-button` and CSS could look like this:

```
<ion-button class="myButton">Hello World, Take Me Somewhere</ion-button>
```

CSS:

```
.myButton {
    font-size: 30px
}
```

That will assign a font size of 30px to everywhere you use the `myButton` class.

Take a look at [ion-button CSS custom properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-custom-properties) for a push in the right direction.

You would also benefit from reading up on CSS and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) is a great starting point.